# Can hidden lines in heading tags and content sections help SEO?

Tags: seo, content, heading, hidden-text

Will the hidden lines in this `H1` tag and content section help SEO?
For example:

`<h1>Red Carpet <span style="display:none"> Made to measure floor carpet in England with Premium quality </span></h1>`

Here I only want to show "Red Carpet" and I don't want to show the rest. So if I make other line hidden, will Google still read that lines and give more strength to my page?  Is there any benefit that I will get adding hidden content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely not, on the contrary, you could be penalized by [cloaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking).

> Cloaking is a search engine optimization (SEO) technique in which the
>   content presented to the search engine spider is different from that
>   presented to the user's browser.

[Google understands CSS styles](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-display-none-20626.html) (especially the ones used to hide content) so that strategy can backfire you easily.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not 'score code' it scores rendered content and placement, little to no weight is assigned to 'styling' because 'design' is subjective, you do not need a word to be in bold or underline for users to take notice.

Ditch the early era SEO books.

Comment: sorry i didnt understand . so i will get any benefit . Please explain